# Add variable values to a .txt file and reading .txt specific line to assign to a variable

Tags: python, variables

So I'm currently in a path to learn code, and I'm currently doing small/beginner projects to get familiar with the python language.

Normally I can get my way around by searching what I want...

But this time I'm stuck.

What I want to do is for most of you really simple...
I want to open a .txt file (code for the file creation is allready there) read a specific line of the .txt and assign it to a variable, this variable is later used to compare with another user input variable...

Sorry if it's not very clear.

Update:

so this is as far as i come...

```py
with open('infos.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

user_master = lines[0]
print(user_master) # this gives the output that i want: "test"

if user_master == "test":
    print("OK") # This does not work, no output on the console...
```

Comment: Where did you try to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.readlines()` to get all the lines and get the line you want by indexing:

```py
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

line = lines[INDEX].strip()
```

Comment: Thanks Pedro, this worked, but i'm still getting an issue, original post updated.

Comment: That's because there's a new line character: `'test\n'`. just strip: `user_master = lines[0].strip()`

Comment: yeap, thats exactly that. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because each line in the list returned from `readlines()` has a trailing newline, so the `if user_master == "test"` fails. The simplest fix is create the list of lines without the ends yourself by utilizing the built-in [`str,splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=splitlines#str.splitlines) method:

```
with open('infos.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()  # Create list of lines with newlines stripped.

user_master = lines[0]
print(user_master) # -> test

if user_master == "test":
    print("OK") # This now works.
```